# XML System.InvalidOperationException: "Повторяющийся атрибут."

Tags: c#, xml, исключения

Кто может растолковать ошибку и помочь исправить, вылетает в строке 
`tagDocument.Add(tagData, new XAttribute("СТРОКА", $"{countofStroka:d3}"))`
после второй иттерации

```cs
foreach (var item in countIterations)
            { 
                XElement tagDocument = new XElement("Document", new XAttribute("ПлСч11", item));
                XElement tagData = new XElement("Data");
                xDoc.Root.Add(tagDocument); //<Document ПлСч11="120111000">

                int countofStroka = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    tagDocument.Add(tagData, new XAttribute("СТРОКА", $"{countofStroka:d3}"));
                    tagData.Add(new XElement("Px", new XAttribute("Value", $"{docs.DocumentList[i].AccountNumber}"), new XAttribute("Num", $"1")));
                    tagData.Add(new XElement("Px", new XAttribute("Value", $"{docs.DocumentList[i].Beginning_balance}"), new XAttribute("Num", $"2")));
                    tagData.Add(new XElement("Px", new XAttribute("Value", $"{docs.DocumentList[i].Beginning_funds_on_the_way}"), new XAttribute("Num", $"3")));
                    tagData.Add(new XElement("Px", new XAttribute("Value", $"{docs.DocumentList[i].End_balance}"), new XAttribute("Num", $"4")));
                    tagData.Add(new XElement("Px", new XAttribute("Value", $"{docs.DocumentList[i].End_funds_on_the_way}"), new XAttribute("Num", $"5")));
                    countofStroka++;
                }
            }
            xDoc.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "xmldoc.xml"));
```

Comment: В элемент `tagDocument` вы добавляете атрибут `СТРОКА` на каждой итерации. Либо вынесите эту строку кода за цикл, либо оберните содержимое в другой узел, как вы делаете в `tagData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляйте новый xml элемент в цикле. Вы в цикле добавляете одни и те же атрибуты в root элемент. Так и получается у вас дублирование атрибутов.